# batch remove first 30 seconds of video file with ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editing, mp4

There are a lot of examples of

```
ffmpeg -ss [start] -i in.mp4 -t [duration] -c copy out.mp4
```

But if I want to use that command for a folder with multiple files (ffmpeg ... *.mp4 ...), how can I specify that [duration] is 'however long the file is' minus the 30 seconds I want to remove?

Comment: Have you tried simply not including the `-t` switch?

Comment: Yes, but what value to pass with -t? If the file is 1:46 long, I want '-t 1:16'.  But for batch shortening multiple files, this will not work.  Is there any way  to specify a relative not an absolute?

Comment: What platform will you be using and what scripting languages are you familiar with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As implied by my comment, the answer to your question is to simply exclude the `-t` argument.

If you know how much of the video you want to capture you can use:

```
ffmpeg -ss [start] -i in.mp4 -t [duration] -c copy out.mp4
```

If you want to just capture the entirety of what remains after the first 30 seconds you would use:

```
ffmpeg -ss [start] -i in.mp4 -c copy out.mp4
```

If you need to be able to do this in bulk you can use any manner of scripting languages or even just an iteration command.

For Windows you can use the following command to trim the first 30 seconds off every mp4 in the current folder (after making a subfolder named "done"; make sure ffmpeg is in the PATH):

```
FORFILES /M *.mp4 /c "cmd /c ffmpeg -ss 30 -i ^"@file^" -c copy ^"done\\@file^""
```

Comment: Thank you - I misread your initial response.  That was so simple that I made it harder than it needed to be!